# Help with java array nullpointerexception

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I keep receiving a NullPointerException while trying to get a string from any array (that is encapsulated within a Vector). I cannot seem to stop the error from happening. It's got to be something simple, however I think that I have been looking at it for too long and I could sure use another set of eyes. Here is my code:

```
 Vector<Event> details = vector.get(i).getEvent();

 for (int x = 0; x < details.size(); x++) {
      Event eDetails = details.get(x);

      person = eDetails.getEventPerson();
      place = eDetails.getEventPlace()[0];
      time = eDetails.getEventTime()[0];

 }
```

So when I try to get the item at position 0 in the array (when x is 0) that is returned from eDetails.getEventTime, a NullPointerException is thrown.

Now, when x is 0 I happen to know that the array element at position 0 of the getEventTime() array is an empty string, but it is NOT a null value. When x is 1 or 2, etc. I can retrieve the time just fine.

The problem is that I will still receive the NullPointerException when I try to do things like the following:

```
 **System.out.println(eDetails.getEventTime.length);**

 or

 String result;

 **if(eDetails.getEventTime[0] == null){**
      result = "";
 } else {
      result = eDetails.getEventTime[0];
 }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean `getEventTime()[0]` in your second block of code? Also, you're not really showing how you populate your objects.

Comment: @Jeremy It should be `getEventTime()[0]` as `getEventTime[0]` would not compile (a method is not an array).

Comment: @extraneon -- I know that, and that's why I assumed. I was just trying to clarify with the OP. But what if the OP had a public instance variable `getEventTime`, however unlikely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure in your second example, it shouldn't be:

`if(eDetails.getEventTime() == null)`

Instead of:

`if(eDetails.getEventTime[0] == null)`

Are you making sure you leave the `[0]` off when you do the null check?

If the function `eDetails.getEventTime()` returns `null`, then you'll get a `NullPointerException` when you try to do `eDetails.getEventTime()[0];`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that when you get `details.get(0).getEventTime()` the array returned is null.

Comment: Could also be `details.get(0).getEventPlace()` that returns null, as that also returns an array (or null).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to figure this out is:

```
Vector<Event> details = vector.get(i).getEvent();

 for (int x = 0; x < details.size(); x++) {
      Event eDetails = details.get(x);
      if (eDetails == null) {
          throw new NullPointerException("eDetails on pos " + x + " is null");
      }

      person = eDetails.getEventPerson();
      Something[] places = Details.getEventPlace();
      if (places == null) {
          throw ....
      }
      place = eDetails.getEventPlace()[0];

      Something[] times =  eDetails.getEventTime();
      if (times == null) {
          throw ....
      }
      time = eDetails.getEventTime()[0];
 }
```

It may not look nice but at least it's informative.